# How to use simple API token together with web based login in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, authentication

I developed a laravel 5.8 web dashboard to allow users to check their power consumption.

I used auth:make to scaffold all auth contollers and related routes, but now I need to expose some API endpoints to be called by my partners and for this I chose simple API token to authenticate (it is sufficient to my problem).

My question is : do I have to write new controllers for login/logout or I can simply use the existing ones (I need it to support both web and API access).

So this code might go for API login (while keeping the original logincontroller for web users)
    // public function login(Request $request)
    // {
    //     $this->validateLogin($request);

```
//     if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
//         $user = $this->guard()->user();
//         $user->generateToken();

//         return response()->json([
//             'data' => $user->toArray(),
//         ]);
//     }

//     return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
// }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a login controller to the API as described above.

Answer (score 1):

When using API token, there is no need for any login/logout controllers. Authentication is done simply by passing along the API token with each request.

Comment: In *some* security models, one may wish to blacklist an API token when a "log out" endpoint is called, so it can no longer be utilized.

Comment: @ceejayoz fair point. But user asks about "simple API token", so this is unlikely of interest.

Comment: I am using the login/logout controllers for the web part, the same application will expose couple API endpoints and it has a web interface (dashboard) so users need to login/logout ...From the API perspective, the caller would login using an endpoint and retrieve a token for subsequent calls...but from web perspective user will login normally ...I thought to add another logincontroller for the API that accept username/password and return user info + token ...while keeping the original controller for the web intact

Comment: so this code might go for the API login while keeping the original logincontroller for web users :     // public function login(Request $request)
    // {
    //     $this->validateLogin($request);

    //     if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
    //         $user = $this->guard()->user();
    //         $user->generateToken();

    //         return response()->json([
    //             'data' => $user->toArray(),
    //         ]);
    //     }

    //     return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    // }